# Web monitoring on SBS2003

Tags: windows-sbs-2003, windows-sbs

Quick question, shouldn't Microsoft Small Business Server 2003 be able to report back on Web usage as well as email usage. I am currently getting a report back with all the email, flaws, memory usage but nothing on web usage. I have been given full responsibility for looking after my companies server but have never really done this before so i thought id look to the pro's.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Gerard

Comment: When you day web monitoring, are you talking about IIS and monitoring sites you host, or are you talking about monitoring peoples acess to the internet?

Comment: Monitoring peoples access to the internet, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you have things setup. If you have SBS premium and have ISA server installed, and all internet traffic is going throuhg your ISA server, then you can view the logs and reports in ISA to see what is happening there. Howeverif your not using ISA, then you need to look to however your traffic is getting to the internet to log it, SBS can't help you here.

Do you have a Router, or firewall hardware setup to connect to the internet, does this have any logging capabilities.

Comment: I have been looking all day for the ISA Server as i read about it previously however i am guessing we dont have it. We have SBS2003 R2 SP2, the set up seems pretty poor 3 years old, there seems to be a netgear adsl router, a UPS, switches (although these could be for the phone lines) and a dell server with 1.6 xenon. 

I want to fully upgrade the system however the MD wants this done first, with individuals access monitored, the full system here is stil currently paper based!

Comment: Ok, SBS 2003 came in 2 versions, Standard and Premium, only Premium had ISA with it, so if you don't have that you won't have ISA. I'd look at your router and see if it does logging, if not you might need to to get some software to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time since I've run a Windows server, but we used to use GFI WebMonitor on a Windows 2003 server.  There's a freeware version available, but as I say it's been a long time since I used it.  We used the ISA plugin, but there's also a standalone version now it seems.

Or you could run something on your router/firewall if it's capable of that.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, since you don't have ISA you're looking at a 3rd party piece of software. If you just have a bog-standard Netgear ADSL router (such as the DG834G) then you won't get any web tracking.

I've used both GFI Webmonitor and Websense. These do more than just logging, and can do proper blocking/filtering as well but will cost you.

E-mail logging, you can track e-mails through Exchange (if you've turned on tracking) on SBS, but it depends what sort of detail you're after if you need more than that.